# how to get System time using play framework and scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

how to get System time using play framework and scala ?

Using playframework2.0 and scala get the system time to web program is there is any different ways...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to paste System time into your Twirl html template, simply add `@` symbol before System

```
@System.currentTimeMillis
```

or

```
@System.nanoTime
```

Update

If u need some format for current time in play then add some helper method in your Twirl template like this:

```
@currentTime = @{
  import java.util.Calendar
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

  val today = Calendar.getInstance.getTime
  val curTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")

  curTimeFormat.format(today)
}
```

then simple call this method in your template:

```
<div>@currentTime</div>
```

You can read about Twirld template engine here: [Scala Template](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates)
and about format rules here: [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @Alexlv the cuurentTime  is String type in view page

Comment: @prasanth Didn't understand, `@currentTime` returns a String, which type do you expect?

Comment: @Alexlv sir it's okay but.. the reslt will print in page was
= { import java.util.Calendar import java.text.SimpleDateFormat val today = Calendat.getInstance.getTime val curTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") curTimeFormat.format(today) } it's becoz of the String type....
1369735571554

Comment: @prasanth Sorry, my mistake, to return a value from a code block in Twirl you should also add `@` before `{` open brace. I've updated the answer, copy-paste it in your tempalte

Comment: @Alexlv   sir the problem solved thanx.. if u don't mind to give  u r mail Id to me...

Answer (score 3):

Try `System.currentTimeMillis` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
val today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```